# Vtiger- Change Browser Title and Logo

Tags: vtiger

I have installed Vtiger 6.1.0 on RHEL 6.5 and I wish to change the default browser title & logo to a custom name & name.

Which file(s) should be edited?

Answer (score 0):

u can change the title in all pages in layouts/vlayouts/modules/Vtiger/vtiger.tpl and hea

Comment: Hey, it looks as you have an incomplete wording there - "and hea" - consider editing it.